# R: attach within function

Tags: r, assign

I want to pass parameters to a function using a list in R. I believe the general consensus is to never use `attach()`. However, it seems to make sense when the goal is to pass a list to a function and attach it as control parameters within the function environment. This is similar to how the parameter list `control` is used in `optim`.

An example:

```
opts = list(N = 50, m = c(0,0,0), V = diag(3^2-0.1,3)+0.1)

a.fun = function(opts){
  attach(opts)
  # N = opts$N; m = opts$m; V = opts$V # isn't this just extra typing?
  # mapply(function(a,b) assign(a,b),names(opts), opts)
  X = MASS::mvrnorm(N, m,  V)
  if( all(m == 0 ) ) VX = 1/(N-1)*t(X) %*% X else VX = var(X)
  return(VX)
}
a.fun(opts)
```

But R complains about objects being masked. So apparently there is no such thing as a local search path.

Is there a better way to do this? I can call `mapply` with assign, but this seems like overkill. It also gets complicated if I want to pass a nested list of parameters.

What are the preferred approaches to assigning parameters within a function if you don't want to make all of them explicit arguments?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with `MASS::mvrnorm(opts$N, opts$m, opts$V)`?

Comment: `X = with(opts, MASS::mvrnorm(N, m,  V))`

Comment: `attach` will put your data columns in the global environment as variables, so you can access it without the name of the data

Comment: you can check this by doing this `search(); N; attach(opts); search(); N`. You get access to N variable after attaching it.

Comment: @Sathish, did you mean `with(opts, a.fun())`? I'm still wondering how that compares to what attach(opts) does within the function.

Comment: `a.fun` takes only one argument - `opts`. But the `mvnorm()` takes three arguments, and its values comes from inside `opts`. So you would not use `a.fun` like your comment above

Comment: what you could do is create your function with three arguments like this `a.fun = function(N, m, V){}` and then use `with(opts, a.fun(N, m, V))`

Comment: Or you could make `a.fun()` a function of no arguments.

Comment: instead you could use `a.fun(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Consider `within` if you really require shorthanded names and avoid repetitively using `opt$` qualifier. The `within` method allows multiple assignments, like *X* and *VX*, and returns objects as part of list:

```
library(MASS)

opts = list(N = 50, m = c(0,0,0), V = diag(3^2-0.1,3)+0.1)

set.seed(62218)

a.fun = function(opts)
  within(opts,{
         X <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, m, V)
         if( all(m == 0 )) VX = 1/(N-1)*t(X) %*% X
         else VX = var(X)
  })

new_opts <- a.fun(opts)
```

**Output**

```
new_opts

$N
[1] 50

$m
[1] 0 0 0

$V
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  9.0  0.1  0.1
[2,]  0.1  9.0  0.1
[3,]  0.1  0.1  9.0

$VX
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  8.2858307 -1.427765  0.2446076
[2,] -1.4277652  5.961497  1.6060490
[3,]  0.2446076  1.606049 10.6135314

$X
              [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
 [1,]  4.665824224 -4.6765516 -2.4337000
 [2,] -2.099468386  1.0783591 -1.8071952
 [3,]  0.336563627  3.0536903  5.8581184
 [4,] -1.650679259  1.8740465  4.0216621
 [5,]  2.734859078  0.4038395 -1.6786622
 [6,]  2.371694498  2.9171274  3.1788630
 [7,]  2.114912549  0.4875905 -2.6360668
 [8,]  0.388181150 -4.4120655 -3.0818534
 [9,]  0.890230929 -1.6782046 -1.7543100
[10,]  5.516072440 -2.4788016  3.8561955
[11,] -0.294422855 -2.4483438 -0.3957462
[12,] -2.750255396  0.3527426 -7.8503780
[13,]  1.017828550 -0.5284536 -2.2027337
[14,]  0.024603249 -1.0532559  0.7042761
[15,] -4.250768981  2.5956117 -1.2632032
[16,] -0.669452033  2.7804910  2.0632924
[17,]  2.262865043  3.7968546  3.0055665
[18,] -1.432375413  1.6244284 -2.4446858
[19,] -3.926978090 -0.3174094  0.8649914
[20,] -0.649302263  0.9863867 -2.7072189
[21,]  7.076439594 -0.1097301 -2.0893510
[22,] -1.406789747 -1.1165661 -0.8801084
[23,]  2.353987384  0.2617199 -2.1814957
[24,] -1.147918893 -4.6585662 -3.6298189
[25,] -6.150519725  2.1693621 -5.2421818
[26,] -3.036748707 -2.8722558 -0.5655960
[27,] -1.969603593  1.5264114 -0.4650506
[28,]  1.980890284 -3.0119946  3.6450285
[29,]  1.581720927 -2.4479232 -3.1369536
[30,] -2.270400502  1.7667221 -3.0248372
[31,] -3.861221387  4.4131931  5.4808763
[32,] -2.448882331  0.2711234 -1.3864900
[33,]  1.680174711 -3.2132275 -4.7415458
[34,] -1.358019507 -1.2661220 -2.1774265
[35,]  1.228070476 -0.3154850 -2.3526299
[36,] -0.001047131  1.8794075  3.5546999
[37,]  5.529764024 -0.2454083 -0.1378435
[38,] -2.856147583  5.1200475 -0.2286176
[39,] -2.262467781 -0.8382753  9.0457395
[40,] -2.285365117  2.0572415 -2.7630034
[41,]  2.451295387  2.4030019 -0.5152660
[42,] -5.846573384  2.0942516 -0.5320590
[43,]  2.468044109  2.8170636 -0.8445475
[44,]  3.629899500  3.5186268  2.3032573
[45,]  2.127080073  1.8658157 -4.8428420
[46,] -0.727723102  0.1421247  1.0030250
[47,] -1.818292041  1.7646028  1.4841969
[48,] -0.271364961 -2.2127800 -3.7642276
[49,]  3.312789724  3.6894729 -3.5619642
[50,] -1.171523623  0.6163963 -2.5790328
```

Comment: That's interesting, not quite what I was expecting, and output could get cluttered...

Comment: Cluttered? All output is retained in **one** named list!

Answer (score 2):

```
opts = list(N = 50, m = c(0,0,0), V = diag(3^2-0.1,3)+0.1)

a.fun = function(N, m, V){
  X = MASS::mvrnorm(N, m,  V)
  if( all(m == 0 ) ) VX = 1/(N-1)*t(X) %*% X else VX = var(X)
  return(VX)
}
with( opts, a.fun(N, m, V))
#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  9.6807152  2.540357 -0.1270927
# [2,]  2.5403570 10.095482  2.8155613
# [3,] -0.1270927  2.815561  9.4595351
```